# "301 Moved Permanently" when trying to curl a local k8s service

Tags: kubernetes

Background:

- `kubectl` version- 1.24
- Docker version- 20.10.17
- MacOS Monterey v12.4

Question:

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.gruntwork.io/a-crash-course-on-kubernetes-a96c3891ad82), trying to set up a local k8s deployment + service.  I successfully ran the following commands:

```
$ kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
Switched to context "docker-desktop".

$ kubectl get nodes
NAME             STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready    control-plane   154m   v1.24.1

$ kubectl create deployment simple-webapp \
  --image training/webapp \
  --replicas=2 \
  --port=5000
deployment.apps/simple-webapp created

$ kubectl get deployments
NAME            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
simple-webapp   2/2     2            2           3m23s

$ kubectl create service loadbalancer simple-webapp \
  --tcp=80:5000
service/simple-webapp created

$ kubectl get services
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        156m
simple-webapp   LoadBalancer   10.109.168.49   <pending>     80:30582/TCP   9m34s
```

However, when I try to run `curl http://localhost` as mentioned in the tutorial, instead of getting the expected output (`Hello world!`), I get:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm brand-new to k8s and have no idea where to start diagnosing the problem.  Not sure if this is useful info, but I ran `docker ps` and it looks like there are two k8s-related docker containers currently running:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND           CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
411b7110b315   training/webapp   "python app.py"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes             k8s_webapp_simple-webapp-5d47556b5-jkvsc_default_9893ef1a-4bc5-43f3-80ac-151d567a89f6_0
9752c12315cc   training/webapp   "python app.py"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes             k8s_webapp_simple-webapp-5d47556b5-269s8_default_5c50b3f8-57a9-4066-bd66-498cd30c758c_0
```

I do see `nginx` referenced in the `curl` output, does this mean that the 301 redirect is coming from inside the `training/webapp` process from the Docker container?  If so, how would I fix this?

EDIT: I tried creating both the deployment and service on a different port (`5001` instead of `5000`), since when I followed part 1 of the tutorial I ran into problems with port 5000 already being in use.  That worked for part 1 of the tutorial, however unfortunately it didn't solve my problem for part 2- I ran into the same `301 redirect` problem when using both port 5000 and 5001.

EDIT 2: When I run `kubectl get pods`, I see the following:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
simple-webapp-5d47556b5-sg9h4   1/1     Running   0          32s
simple-webapp-5d47556b5-xw2nh   1/1     Running   0          32s
```

I continue to see the `301 redirect` even after running `curl` to confirm the pods are up.

EDIT 3: I *do* notice that when I run `kubectl get nodes`, the single node has a role of `control-plane`, *not* `control-plane,master` as noted in the tutorial.  I also notice that running `kubectl get services` shows that the `EXTERNAL-IP` of the loadbalancer is `pending`, not `localhost` as expected from the tutorial.  Are either of these facts relevant?

EDIT 4: Further down in the tutorial, we delete both the deployment and service that were previously created, and we re-create them using `deployment.yml` and `service.yml` files, alongside the commands `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml` and `kubectl apply -f service.yml`.  When I copy/paste the YAML from the tutorial into new files with the specified filenames, I get the same `301 Redirect` error.

EDIT 5: In [this Hacker News comment thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=32216700), I saw that Kubernetes had removed support for Docker as of v1.24.  I had previously upgraded my `kubectl` Homebrew version to 1.24 because my prior version didn't support the `--replicas` flag.  When I read this thread, I downgraded to v1.22 (the previous version), verified the version was correct via `kubectl version`, deleted/recreated the previously-created deployment and service, and tried `curl` again.  I still get the `301 redirect` error.

EDIT 6: Here's the full output of `curl -v http://localhost`:

```
curl -v http://localhost 
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.21.2
< Date: Mon, 25 Jul 2022 04:53:40 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://localhost/
< 
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.2</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Looks like it's trying to redirect from `http` to `https`?  Could this be some setting within the `training/webapp` Docker image?

Also, here's the result of `sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep :80`:

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep :80
nginx     3582   richiethomas    6u  IPv4 0x63a69bc74912e747      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     3582   richiethomas    7u  IPv6 0x63a69bbdb3ebcbe7      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     3701   richiethomas    6u  IPv4 0x63a69bc74912e747      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     3701   richiethomas    7u  IPv6 0x63a69bbdb3ebcbe7      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: use `netstat -alp` to figure who is listening at port 80. Also, the `301` response will have a `Location` header, whats the value ?

Comment: @YK1 I posted the output of `curl -v`.  As for who is listening on port 80, I wasn't able to get `netstat` to produce the output you asked for, but I've also updated the question to include the result of `lsof`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have `nginx` running on port `80`(and `443`) on your system. Likely, another docker container outside kubernetes, or directly on your system. It already has taken port `80`, hence your LoadBalancer is in pending state.

Either stop that nginx service or use another port like `8080` for your LoadBalancer:

```
$ kubectl create service loadbalancer simple-webapp \
       --tcp=8080:5000
```

The `training/webapp` does not use nginx.

Comment: Changing the port from `80` to `8080` did the trick!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the service using http://nodename/nodeip:30581

```
simple-webapp   LoadBalancer   10.109.168.49   <pending>     80:30582/TCP   9m34s
```

Note; Change the service type to NodePort from Loadbalancer. Loadbalancer only works on cloud providers like AWS, Azure etc.